# JPanel always become full screen size if its inside of full screen JFrame

Tags: java, swing, jframe, jpanel, fullscreen

When I add JPanel into full screen JFrame, JPanel sizing does not work and JPanel becomes full screen too, whats problem here and how to fix?

```
import java.awt.*;
import javax.swing.*;

public class pcb extends JFrame {   
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        JFrame pcb = new JFrame();
        pcb.setUndecorated(true);
        pcb.setBackground(new Color(0, 0, 0, 0)); // transparent jframe
        pcb.setExtendedState(JFrame.MAXIMIZED_BOTH); // full size
        
        JPanel timerFrame = new JPanel();
        timerFrame.setLayout(null);
        timerFrame.setSize(350, 200);
        timerFrame.setBackground(new Color(100, 150, 100, 255));
        timerFrame.setVisible(true);
        pcb.add(timerFrame);
        
        pcb.setVisible(true);
    }
}
```

Comment: Don't fit the layout managers, they are there for a reason.  Why do you want to "manually" manage the size/placement anyway?

Comment: You never set a layout manager for your JFrame. Every content pane is initialized to use a BorderLayout, and every JPanel defaults to a FlowLayout. The JFrame layout manager is what impacts the child components including your JPanel size/location, so if you want to use absolute positioning then set your JFrame to a null layout instead of your JPanel like so `pcb.setLayout(null);` however, this is typically NOT a good idea unless you know exactly what you are doing and the knock-on effects.